# Posterior probability, Dynamic Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian-network

[image]

I need help with part c).

However, these are the answers I got for a) & b):

a) P(S1) = P(S1 | S0) * P(S0) + P(S1 | ¬S0) * P(¬S0) = 0.65

b) P(¬Red_eyes and ¬Yawn | S1) = P(¬Red_eyes | S1) * (¬Yawn | S1) = 0.8 * 0.9 = 0.72

And my answer for c)

P(S1 | e1) = [P(e1 | S1) * P(S1)] / P(e1) = [0.72 * 0.65]/ 0.542 = **0.864**

where P(e1) = P(e1 | S1) * P(S1) + P(e1 | ¬S1) * P(¬S1) =0.542

This is the given solution to c):

I don't understand how they got 0.136? Why is the answer written like that? Isn't the right answer just 0.864?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the $\langle a,b\rangle$ notation mean?

Comment: I don't know @joriki

Comment: The same example with the same notation is also treated in [these lecture notes](https://www.kth.se/social/upload/5256c2b7f276544140e27a42/lecture10_DBN.pdf).

Comment: By looking at the fourth 'slide' on page 3 I guess that 0.864 is the final answer, which is the same answer I got. But is 0.136 the probability of being in state S2 given the same evidence? P(S2 | e1) = 1 - P(S1 | e1) = 0.136 @joriki

Comment: $\langle a, b\rangle$ appears to be the answer using $S_1$ and $\lnot S_1$.  See how $\mathsf P(\mathbf{e_1}\mid\lnot S_1) = 0.21$